# What is best way to find the "parent" sizer in nested sizers?

Tags: wxpython, nested, sizer

In wxpython I have a GridBagSizer, gs, with some nested sizers `s1` and `s2` and a button `b`, in a single cell.

On an `EVT_BUTTON` event I get the button object. To move the button object around in the grid, to a different grid cell, I need to move the top level sizer, s1, which is the direct "child" (if that's the correct term) of the GridBagSizer, gs.  What is the best way to find the top-level sizer?

`object.GetContainingSizer()` returns the button object's sizer, s2, but I can't see how to get to s1.  Do I need to store the reference to s1 in my s2 (or b) object? This seems rather inelegant?

```
# pseudocode
panel=wx.Panel( None )
gs= wx.GridBagSizer()
s1= wx.BoxSizer()
s2= wx.BoxSizer()
b= wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'AButton')

s2.Add( b )
s1.Add( s2 )
gs.Add( s1, (row,col))
```

**Answer (so far)**: I found a piece of code for which I don't know who to credit - seems to have something to do with dabo. It's in dGridSizer.py, but it did a similar thing I'm looking for:

```
szitm= grid_sizer.FindItemAtPosition( (row,col) )
if szitm:
    if szitm.IsWindow():
        itm=szitm.GetWindow()
    elif szitm.IsSizer():
        itm=szitm.GetSizer()
    try: # in case some other IsSomething() I don't have covered
        grid_sizer.SetItemPosition( itm, (newrow,col))
    except:
        pass
```

That seems to work in all the cases I have in my grid so far.  Not sure I understand it at this point, I'll have to dig into the code later - now just have to make this work.

Comment: There is the GetContainingSizer widget method, which will give you the sizer that the widget has been added to.  But since sizers don't keep track of their parents, only their children, there isn't a way to go from a sizer to the sizer that it is being managed by, if there is one.

Answer (score 6):

A trick I've done sometimes is to take one of the widgets managed by the sizer I'm working with, get its parent, and then get the parent's sizer.  Unless you're doing something really weird that should be the top-level parent sizer of the sizer you're working with (or the sizer itself if it is the one at the top of that hierarchy.

`parentSizer = widget.GetParent().GetSizer()`

Comment: That is a good idea - unfortunately it won't work in this case, I have the windows(widgets) all set with parent of the main wxPanel, and many levels of sizers deep before getting to the sizer I'm looking for. So your example code returns the wxPanel's wxBoxSizer that is hierarchically far above the level of even the GridBagSizer and therefore it's cells, AND I wouldn't know which child sizer it would be, and I think it would get ugly sorting through the many layers of sizers from the top.



Thanks

Comment: I found an answer I'll post above in my original.  Also have a question for you there.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to store a reference in the sizer, but you do have to store a reference to the sizer. Make your sizer definitions like this:

```
self.gs = wx.GridBagSizer()
self.s1 = wx.BoxSizer()
self.s2 = wx.BoxSizer()
```

Then you can access the sizers elsewhere in your application and Add or Remove widgets as needed.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I was hoping to not have to keep track of them, due to the sheer number.  The actual code has many levels of sizers and would be horrible to keep track of.  That is why I was thinking inside the sizer make a sizer._dales_parent_sizer variable to hold it.
As I mentioned in Robins post - I'll post the answer I found.